# 'Could not find a MudhornDescriberCapabilities service provider' when uploading to the Apple Store

Tags: electron, appstore-approval

I have build my electron app correctly and I'm trying to upload it to the Apple store (for Macs, not Iphones). It is uploaded via the Transporter app (https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12). But I receive the following warning.

`Could not find a MudhornDescriberCapabilities service provider`

When I look up the warning message, I cannot find anything useful.

I don't have anything MudhornDescripberCapabilities in my code nor did I have this error a few weeks ago.

The application is a React App that runs on Electron. The update can still be reviewed by Apple & has passed previously with this warning.

Comment: I received it for iOS transfer as well so not just a Mac error I guess...I got it when I tried to use Transporter to upload my ios bundle to Apple

Comment: I'm also using the transporter. I have updated the original question to mention this fact.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same curious message uploading an update to Apple Books through iTunes Producer. Samer routine as always, and Never seen it before.
The upload was however successful as confirmation looked normal. I can't find any online reference to that weird term -- must be an internal mudhorn doohickey.